# I can't display data from rest service in the navigator only they are shown in database tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'am working with TFS for the First time,I have created a restful web service with ASP.net the problem is that the navigator doesn't show me the data that it is stored in dataBase,per example:

```
var Subjects = new List<Subject>
{
new Subject{Libel="Sub1"},
new Subject{Libel="Sub2"},
new Subject{Libel="Sub3"},
new Subject{Libel="Sub4"},
};
Subjects.ForEach(s =>
{
s.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;
context.Subjects.Add(s);
context.SaveChanges();
});
```

this model will intialize data into database,so I can see data in the database table Subject but not in the web service
any Help please

thanks

UPDate:

this is the model file:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

namespace SMA.Entities.Models
{
    public partial class Subject : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Libel { get; set; }

        public virtual List<SubjectLevel> SubjectLevels { get; set; }

        public Subject()
        {
            SubjectLevels = new List<SubjectLevel>();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the model file for the SubjectLevel Entity:

```
public partial class SubjectLevel : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Coef { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public Int64 SubjectId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LevelId")]
        public virtual Level Level { get; set; }
        public Int64 LevelId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }

        public SubjectLevel()
        {
            Schedules = new List<Schedule>();
        }
```

The Subject Controller:

```
public class SubjectController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly ISubjectService _SubjectService;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWorkAsync;

        public SubjectController(
            IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync,
            ISubjectService SubjectService)
        {
            _unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
            _SubjectService = SubjectService;
        }

        // GET: odata/Subjects
        [HttpGet]
        [Queryable]
        public IQueryable<Subject> GetSubject()
        {

            var l= _SubjectService.Queryable().ToList();
            return _SubjectService.Queryable();
        }

        // GET: odata/Subjects(5)
        [Queryable]
        public SingleResult<Subject> GetSubject([FromODataUri] Int64 key)
        {
            return SingleResult.Create(_SubjectService.Queryable().Where(t => t.Id == key));
        }

        // PUT: odata/Subjects(5)
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(Int64 key, Subject Subject)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (key != Subject.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            Subject.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;
            _SubjectService.Update(Subject);

            try
            {
                await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!SubjectExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                throw;
            }

            return Updated(Subject);
        }

        // POST: odata/Subjects
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Subject Subject)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            Subject.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
            _SubjectService.Insert(Subject);

            try
            {
                await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (SubjectExists(Subject.Id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                throw;
            }

            return Created(Subject);
        }

        //// PATCH: odata/Subjects(5)
        [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] Int64 key, Delta<Subject> patch)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            Subject Subject = await _SubjectService.FindAsync(key);

            if (Subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            patch.Patch(Subject);
            Subject.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!SubjectExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                throw;
            }

            return Updated(Subject);
        }

        // DELETE: odata/Subjects(5)
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(string key)
        {
            Subject Subject = await _SubjectService.FindAsync(key);

            if (Subject == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Subject.ObjectState = ObjectState.Deleted;

            _SubjectService.Delete(Subject);
            await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }


        private bool SubjectExists(Int64 key)
        {
            return _SubjectService.Query(e => e.Id == key).Select().Any();
        }
    }
```

The view:

```
<h4>Subjects</h4>
            <a href="api/Subjects" target="_blank">(GET => api/Subjects) GetAll &raquo;</a><br />
```

Comment: I'am using google chrome sorry I mean web browser :)

Comment: Then show the code that loads the entries from the database and displays them.

Comment: In fact I'am initalizing the database tables with those data,I have used the code above to insert the data into the database table Subject

Comment: I'm sure you believe the data is in your database, but you don't show the code that reads the records from there, nor do you properly explain the problem. Please update your post with your code and the actual problem. Also read [ask].

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for your reply sorry for late it was an internet connexion problem

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: That does not show how you load the entities from the database. Your problem is _"I don't see the Schedules on my MVC site"_, so you need to show your controller and view.